# Check if image is valid

Tags: electron

I want to check, if a given image file is valid (means displayable in a browser window and not getting a [image] indicating, that the image cannot be displayed. This is the code I tried:

```
var bWindow;

bWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({"show": false});
bWindow.loadURL("file://defect.png");

bWindow.webContents.on("did-fail-load", function (event, errCode, errDescription) {
    console.log("error", errDescription);
});
bWindow.webContents.on("did-finish-load", function () {
    console.log("success");
});
```

expecting to get "error". But I always get "success". How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score -1):

Try-

```
function checkImage(imageSrc, good, bad) {
 var img = new Image();
img.onload = good; 
img.onerror = bad;
img.src = imageSrc;
 }

 checkImage("foo.gif", function(){ alert("good"); }, function(){     alert("bad"); } );
```

Comment: Ths does not work in Electron. We are not in the browser ;-)

Comment: onerror is only invoked if the image is not there. Not if it is invalid.